# Within bounds but not intersection

Tags: c#

For some reason I am not grasping this simple problem.

```
if ((paulBoss.Position.Y <= sharkPlayer.Position.Y 
 && paulBoss.Collision.Bottom <= sharkPlayer.Collision.Bottom)
|| (paulBoss.Position.Y >= sharkPlayer.Position.Y 
 && paulBoss.Collision.Bottom >= sharkPlayer.Collision.Bottom))
{
    bossState = BossState.Charge;
}
```

Essentially I'm trying to determine if the boss can actually hit the player before charging, but it's charging even when it's not within reach of the player.

Comment: I think a little more context is required to correctly identify the issue. The `Collision.Bottom` pieces are unclear. The players position and bottom must be less than the bosses or they must be greater... It seems like it will always evaluate to true. However, you could have a great bottom and lesser position or vice versa, is that actually the logic you expect? Does the latter situation actually occur (> bottom and < position)?

Comment: Sorry the Collision property is just the bounding box. It is basically position.y + height of texture

Comment: Oh ok, i think I know the problem :)

Comment: Don't you have a `Collision.Top` or something like that? Feels like the second test is wrong. A picture would go a long way here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(x <= y OR x >= y)` is functionally identical to `true` for any value of `x` or `y`

In order words, recheck your conditions. You didn't share implementation specifics, but I'm guessing your if statement is always true.